# Make empty cells to input integers for a table of the package: rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I want to make empty cells in the  rhandsontable but if we use `NA`, then it will be check boxes instead of empty cells in a table of the package rhandsontable .

---

Thank you,  @ismirsehregal. 
In the following code, we can make a table with empty cell..

Using `NA_integer_` instead `NA`, we can make a empty cell.

**Solution of @ismirsehregal**

```
     library(rhandsontable)
        library(shiny)

        foo <- function(M = 2,
                        Q = 3,
                        C = 4) {
          DF <- data.frame(
            m = 1,  
            q = 2,  
            c = 3,

            # To make empty cells, we should use NA_integer_ instead NA.

 h= rep(NA_integer_, M * Q * C),  # Here, we should use NA_integer_ instead NA
 f = rep(NA_integer_, M * Q * C) # Here, we should use NA_integer_ instead NA
                      )

                  ui <- shiny::fluidPage(

                shiny::sidebarLayout(
                  shiny::sidebarPanel(


                    rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput("hot")
                  ),
                  shiny::mainPanel()
                )
              )

              server <-  function(input, output) {
                values <- shiny::reactiveValues()

                ## Handsontable
                shiny::observe({
                  if 

    (!is.null(input$hot)) {
                DF = rhandsontable::hot_to_r(input$hot)
              } else {
                if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
                  DF <- DF
                else
                  DF <- values[["DF"]]
              }
              values[["DF"]] <- DF
              values[["dataList"]] <- list(
                NL = input$Number_of_lesions,
                NI = input$Number_of_images,
                h = DF$h,
                f = DF$f,
                m = DF$m,
                q = DF$q,
                c = DF$c,
                C = input$C,
                M = input$M,
                Q = input$Q
              )
            })

            output$hot <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({
              DF <- values[["DF"]]
              if (!is.null(DF))
                rhandsontable::rhandsontable(DF,
                                             stretchH = "all")
            })
          }
          shiny::runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
          return(invisible())

        } # function

        foo()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, function `m_q_c_vector_from_M_Q_C` is missing.

Comment: Thank you @ismirsehregal, my example code was redundant and I reduced it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `NA_integer_` instead of `NA`. For `NA` the resulting vector is of type "logical" which causes the display of the checkboxes.

Please see the following:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

foo <- function(M = 2,
                Q = 3,
                C = 4) {
  DF <- data.frame(
    m = 1, # m_q_c_vector_from_M_Q_C(M, Q, C)$m,
    q = 2, # m_q_c_vector_from_M_Q_C(M, Q, C)$q,
    c = 3, # m_q_c_vector_from_M_Q_C(M, Q, C)$c,
    h = rep(NA_integer_, M * Q * C),
    f = rep(NA_integer_, M * Q * C)
  )

  ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::tags$head(
      shiny::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
    ),
    # Color

    shiny::sidebarLayout(
      shiny::sidebarPanel(
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "Number_of_MCMC_samples",
          "Number of MCMC samples:",
          min = 10,
          max = 11111,
          value = 111
        ),
        shiny::h4(shiny::helpText(" Larger is better."))
        ,
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "Number_of_MCMC_chains",
          "Number of MCMC chains:",
          min = 1,
          max = 4,
          value = 1
        ),
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "Number_of_lesions",
          "Number of lesions:",
          min =  1,
          max = 1111,
          value = 259#
        ),
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "Number_of_images",
          "Number of images:",
          min = 1,
          max = 1111,
          value = 57
        ),
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "C",
          "Number of C:",
          min =  1,
          max = 11,
          value = 3
        ),
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "M",
          "Number of M:",
          min = 1,
          max = 7,
          value = 4
        ),
        shiny::sliderInput(
          "Q",
          "Number of Q:",
          min = 1,
          max = 7,
          value = 5
        ),
        shiny::h1("Data"),
        shiny::h4(
          shiny::helpText("Right-click on the table to delete/insert rows.")
        ),
        shiny::h4(shiny::helpText("Double-click on a cell to edit")),
        rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
        # Table of h and f ###########################################################
        shiny::h5(shiny::helpText(" h = hit = True Positive = TP.")),
        shiny::h5(shiny::helpText(" f = false alarms = False Positive = FP."))
      ),
      shiny::mainPanel()
    )
  )

  server <-  function(input, output) {
    values <- shiny::reactiveValues()

    ## Handsontable
    shiny::observe({
      if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
        DF = rhandsontable::hot_to_r(input$hot)
      } else {
        if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
          DF <- DF
        else
          DF <- values[["DF"]]
      }
      values[["DF"]] <- DF
      values[["dataList"]] <- list(
        NL = input$Number_of_lesions,
        NI = input$Number_of_images,
        h = DF$h,
        f = DF$f,
        m = DF$m,
        q = DF$q,
        c = DF$c,
        C = input$C,
        M = input$M,
        Q = input$Q
      )
    })

    output$hot <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({
      DF <- values[["DF"]]
      if (!is.null(DF))
        rhandsontable::rhandsontable(DF,
                                     stretchH = "all")
    })
  }
  shiny::runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
  return(invisible())

} # function

foo()
```